# What does 'glory' mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-in-context

I think it means ***great beauty***, but I am not sure.

> The greatest ***glory*** in living lies not in never falling, but in
> rising every time we fall.

Comment: **glory** can mean **great beauty**, but it is not often uses with this meaning What makes you think that it might be appropriate in this case.

Comment: It is a quite unusual usage. Can you tell us where you saw it with a link please?

Comment: Nelson Mandela is said to say that, but I'm not sure who created it first.

Answer (score 1):

No, here it means ["very great honor"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/glory) -- you might paraphrase as, "It is most honorable to get up and try, again and again."